# How to keep app running in background to monitor movements

Tags: ios, background, long-running-processes, background-application

I am implementing an application to monitor user's movement/activity (when playing game/sport or sleeping in bed) using accelerometer via CMMotionManager, so I need to keep app running in background to record data, I tried to use background task but app can only run in background in about 3 minutes while I need it to be able to run up to 10-12 hrs, I know there are many apps on iTunes store can run in background, I searched but still not find out a good solution yet

Anyone know how to do this without making app be rejected, please help me, Thanks.